# Dataframe styling through Python

Tags: python, dataframe, textbox, styles, cell

I am trying to send outlook mail via python. I import some data from excel files using dataframe and after some filtering I send them where the body of the mail is:

```
    body = '<html><body>'+df.to_html()+'</body></html>'
```

I get a table but the cells are not aligned.I can not use `justify='left/write'` as I want the cells to be center aligned,not just the column headers. I have used styles but it did not work either:

```
df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns,**{'width':'10em', 'text-align':'center'})\
```

I tried this too and it did not work.

```
p=HTML(df.to_html(classes= 'table text-align:center'))
```

After surfing through similar problems I found another solution:

```
s = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
s.render()
```

However it makes the `border` of the table disappear.So I modified it:

```
s = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center','border-color':'Black','border-width':'thin','border-style':'dotted'})
```

This gives `border` to the cells. But it looks like `each cell` is inside individual `textbox,`not like a `table`. How do I get this done?

The final result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Seems like you have to attend a HTML & CSS crash-course.

Comment: I know that already. I am still in the learning phase of Python.
Do you have anything else that would help?

Comment: post a picture and i'll fix it for you.

Comment: I have attached the picture in the post.

Comment: you're targeting `subset=df.columns`, what you want to do is to target `subset=df.rows`

Comment: This gives Attribute Error
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'`

Comment: Could you please post all of your code? Or a working example? Try `row` otherwise.

Comment: Have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html otherwise.

Comment: 1. row/rows gives the same exact error.
2. I have read this doc already multiple times and it helped me to get the final result. However, i could not find anything that would help to make the table look like one, not like multiple text box.

Comment: `s = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center','border-color':'Black','border-width':'thin','border-style':'solid'}).set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('border-width', 1),('border-style','solid')]}]).set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})`

This is the exact code that gave me the output that has been attached with the post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to style `td` and `th` elements of your table.

```py
style_td = dict(selector="td", props=[('border-collapse', 'collapse')])

style_th = dict(selector="th", props=[('border-collapse', 'collapse')])
```

After that you can put this dicts to your dataframe.style.set_table_styles part. Like;

```py
df_styled = df.style.set_table_styles([style_td, style_th])
```

It works for me. And also you can add more CSS option props to your each HTML element.

Answer (score -1):

You can exactly do that without much editing, you only have to add:

```
'border-collapse':'collapse'

html = df[['Column 1','Column 2',]].style.hide_index().set_properties(**{'font-size': '11pt','background-color': '#edeeef','border-color': 'black','border-style' :'solid' ,'border-width': '0px','border-collapse':'collapse'}).applymap(style1,subset = 'Column 1').applymap(Style2 ,subset = 'Column 2').render()
```

NOTE : You can ignore the other parts of this above code-snipet , only useful thing is  - -   'border-collapse':'collapse'

So now the border inside border will be resolved to only one border

[image: A simple single line border]

Comment: where should I put 'border-collapse':'collapse' ?